# Entity Framework asp.net MVC foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, cascade

I am trying to code the following in code first... since I am just begining I am not able to.. please help.. thanks in advance
1. Student: Student will have student ID, First Name, Last Name
Student should belong to one class and one section(basically one to one relationship with each entity)
2. Classes: Class will have ClassId, Name
Class should have collection of students and collection of sections(basically many to many relationship with each entity)
3. Sections: Section will have SectionID, Name
Section should belong to one class and should have collection of students(basically one to one relation with class and one to many relation with Students)
Below is the code for the same

Students.cs

```
public class Students  
{  
    public int StudentsId { get; set; }  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }  
    public string LastName { get; set; }  
    public string UserName { get; set; }  
    public decimal Grade { get; set; }  
    public int ClassesId { get; set; }  
    public Classes Classes { get; set; }  
    public int SectionsId { get; set; }  
    public Sections Sections { get; set; }  
}
```

Classes.cs

```
public class Classes  
{  
    public int ClassesId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public ICollection<Sections> Sections { get; set; }  
}
```

Sections.cs

```
public class Sections
{
    public int SectionsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ClassesId { get; set; }

    public Classes Classes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

If I do this I get error saying:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Sections_dbo.Classes_ClassesId' on table 'Sections' may cause
>   cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I know I can get rid of this error using fluent APIs and telling not to cascade on delete, but I don't want to do that. Is there any other solution to this?? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current model, no, there is no other way than disabling casdading delete for some of the relationships.

All your relationships are required, that means that if a class is deleted you delete the sections and the students of that class (`Classes` has a not exposed collection of students due to the required navigation property `Classes` in `Students`). But if the sections are deleted the students of that sections are deleted as well - and that's the second delete path to `Students`.

I don't know the exact meaning of your model but to me it sounds strange to delete all students of a class if the class gets deleted. Does a student always *must* have a class or couldn't he temporarily be without class assignment (and section assignment as well)? Maybe the student has a holiday semester for half a year and doesn't participate in any class?

In that case you could make the relationships of `Students` optional. Just declare the foreign key properties as nullable:

```
public class Students  
{
    //...
    public int? ClassesId { get; set; }  
    public Classes Classes { get; set; }  
    public int? SectionsId { get; set; }  
    public Sections Sections { get; set; }  
}
```

This would fix your problem of multiple cascading delete paths in the `Students` class because by default optional relationships don't have cascading delete enabled. The relationship between `Classes` and `Sections` is still required, so deleting a class will delete all sections belonging to the class as well, but it won't delete the students anymore.

Comment: Actually the idea is of creating a School structure... In Schools there are different classes... and each class has different sections for example. first standard section A, first standard section B, Second standard section A, Second standard section B, Second standard section C etc. Here student actually belong to a section and sections belong to a class but eventually students also belong to class and class will have to be referred in the code number of times for a student so I feel there has to be a relationship. Please help if there is any other kind of way to define this relationship.

Comment: Just wanted to add to that... Here the class sizes are large so they are divided into sections...for example if there are 80 students in first standard then they will have 40 students each in two sections A and B in First Standard...Here if the student is enrolled in school has to belong to a class and if class has sections should belong to one section inside class...if a section is deleted then students should move to a default section in a class... say section A.. It would be great if you could help me with model logic for this... thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @AmitRaya: To me it sounds that your model is actually fine then. You just need to disable cascading delete for the relationship between `Students` and `Classes` and between `Students` and `Sections`. It's not only technically necessary, but also from business viewpoint cascading delete sounds wrong to me: Students shouldn't be deleted when a class is deleted, they should be assigned to another class.